# How can I run an open node with RPC restricted only to localhost?

Tags: monerod, rpc

Currently, I can run an open node and connect my wallet from another system (with `restricted-rpc` to be safe)

***OR***

I can run the node with RPC enabled (so I can **monitor from localhost**, eg `monerod status`, `monerod stop_daemon`, etc) in which case I should not bind to an external IP address (correct?).

How can I configure `monerod` to do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of dodging the question, but it seems to be logically impossible, so...
A way to "kinda" do both is to use a ssh tunnel to connect to your node's host, then connect through localhost, and bind RPC to loopback only.

Instructions on how to use ssh are found all over the internet, and I won't offer guidance there as I'd be more wrong than what you can find.

Comment: Okay, was hoping that there was something like `restricted-rpc` for non-localhost connections only.

Comment: Found feature request [#835](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/835) which seems like it would work (just firewall off the unrestricted port).